# NHibernate, HTTPApplication and Exceptions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asmx

I've tried to find answers to this question but I don't find any clear one. 
So my questions are, in the code I paste :

- Is it right to throw an exception in this way ? (The Super exception)
- Is the Dispose excecuted ?
- What happens with the HTTPApplication ? (is the end of the lifecycle executed ?)

This code is executed in a .NET 2.0 webservice.

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader ("Credentials", Required=true)]
public void DoSomething ()
{
    if (AuthenticationModule.IsValid (Credentials) && AuthenticationModule.CanPerformAction (Credentials, Permissions.DoSomething)) { 
        using (ISession session = NHibernateUtil.SessionFactory.OpenSession()) {

            if(Condition)
                throw new ApplicationException("Super exception");

            session.Close ();
        }
    }
    else
        throw new SecurityException("Invalid user or inssuficient privileges");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `using` statement ensures that Dispose() is called for the given object, see its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

The HTTPApplication documents the event order in its [class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx). The EndRequest event is executed even in the face of an unhandled exception.